# How to prove this Haskell code using equational reasoning

Tags: haskell, recursion, proof, equational-reasoning

I found this exercise on equational reasoning and proofs in Haskell. The following code is given:

```
type Stack = [Int]
type Code = [Op]
data Op = PUSH Int | ADD
deriving (Show)
--
-- Stack machine
--
exec :: Code -> Stack -> Stack
exec [ ] s = s
exec (PUSH n : c) s = exec c (n:s)
exec (ADD:c) (m:n:s) = exec c (n+m : s)
--
-- Interpeter
--
data Expr = Val Int | Add Expr Expr
deriving (Show)
eval :: Expr -> Int
eval (Val n) = n
eval (Add x y) = eval x+eval y
--
-- Compiler
--
comp :: Expr -> Code
comp (Val n) = [PUSH n]
comp (Add x y) = comp x ++ comp y ++ [ADD]
```

Now I have to prove that `exec(comp e) s = eval e : s`.

So I found this answer so far:

We have to prove that `exec (comp e) s = eval e : s`.

First case: Assume `e = (Val n)`. Then `comp (Val n) = [PUSH n]`, so we have to prove that `exec ([PUSH n]) s = eval ([PUSH n] : s)`. We find that `exec ([PUSH n]) s = exec [] (n:s) = (n:s)` using the function definition of exec.

Now `eval (Val n) : s = n : s`. The first case is OK!

Second case: Assume `e = (Add x y)`. Then `comp (Add x y) = comp x ++ comp y ++ [ADD]`.

But now I'm struggling with this recursive use of comp. Should I be using some form of trees and induction on these trees to prove this? I'm not completely sure how to do that.

Comment: note that you are missing one line in `exec _ [] = error "ADD applied to an empty or singleton stack"`

Comment: You will probably need a lemma about `exec` - in particular you have `exec (a ++ b) s = exec b (exec a s)`. This would allow you write `exec (comp x ++ comp y ++ [ADD])` as `exec [ADD] (exec (comp y) (exec (comp x)))`

Comment: Thank you! But how can I prove the comp x and comp y then?

Answer (score 3):

When the first argument to `exec` is a list, the two possibilities are:

```
exec (PUSH n: codes)  -- #1
exec (ADD   : codes)  -- #2
```

In the induction step you get to assume that the proposition holds for `codes`, i.e. you may assume:

```
exec codes s = eval codes : s
```

for *any* value of *s* -- Keep this in mind - this is usually the key step in any induction proof.

Start by expanding #1 using the code you've written for `exec`:

```
exec (PUSH n: codes) s == exec codes (n:s)
                       == ...
                       == ...
                       == eval (PUSH n: codes) : s
```

Can you see a place to use the induction hypothesis?